# Newlines while saving variable to file - bash

Tags: bash

I have mulitiple ip adresses in a variable.

```
ActiveIPs= 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.3
```

I want to save them to a file like this

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
```

how do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
rm -f file
for i in ${ActiveIPs}
do
  echo ${i} >> file
done
```

Answer (score 3):

One-liner:

```
printf "%s\n" $ActiveIPs > ActiveIPs.txt
```

This behaves as follows:

- $ActiveIPs is expanded by the shell.

  - [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) breaks it at whitespace characters. The pieces are passed to printf as individual parameters.
  - If it were quoted as in `printf "%s\n" "$ActiveIPs"`, it would not be split, and it would be passed to printf as a single parameter.
- printf takes the first argument and formats it with "%s\n".
- If printf is given more parameters than format specifiers, it reuses the format string. In this case, it has 1 format specifier (%s), so it applies "%s\n" to the remaining parameters, one by one.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I tried your command and it didn't work, it simply printed all IPs in one line. But that was a shell issue. Mea culpa, I can convert -1 to +1 only if you edit your answer (e.g. explicitly include redirection to a file, as asked by OP).

Comment: This is not a shell issue: the IPs will be printed on one line.

Comment: @eldering Did you quote $ActiveIPs? See edited answer.

Comment: @eldering: The problem I faced was that `zsh` doesn't do word splitting like `bash` unless the `SH_WORD_SPLIT`option is set. This is easily forgotten and I didn't knew that the shell's `printf` can take more arguments than format specifiers (IMHO unlike C's printf?!). Now with the additional explanation, I really think that this an elegant answer.

Comment: @ignis: sorry, I wasn't aware of this special feature of bash of reusing the format string, and assumed quoted $ActiveIPs. Thanks for pointing this out.